# How do I get Google Drive to open text files with arbitrary extensions as text files?

Tags: text-editors, google-drive, google-docs, textfiles

I have text files on Google Drive that do not end with the `.txt` suffix (such as: .r, .bas, .awk...).
I want to view them using the Drive Notepad app, but it does not recognize the files as text.
Is there a way I can get these files to be recognized as text?

Comment: It seems to be doing it for me already. I've tested uploading a file called file.arb using the webui - it renames it to file.arb.txt and renaming it back seems to just leave it associated as a text type file. The desktop client dosen't seem to work for me, I'll test it once I manage to get it to, and post an answer if so

Comment: Same question also here: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/66776/how-to-force-a-file-with-a-different-extension-to-preview-as-a-text-file-in-goog

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you just want to view the files you can do the following:

1. Save the file with a .txt extension, i.e. `filename.bat` becomes `filename.bat.txt`
2. Add it to google drive
3. Remove the .txt extension, `filename.bat.txt` goes back to `filename.bat`

Google determines the context type based on the extension and retains that through future file renamings, so you'll be able to view it even after changing back to the original extension.

Comment: Well the best thing is if i can edit it straight from google drive. I thoght of the option of adding ".txt" to the end but i am looking for something more elegant

Comment: well, the I would suggest going to the settings, upload settings, and select convert uploads to google docs format.  That way, if you ever needed them to be in a text format again, then save them as a text file.  That way you could edit them all you want.

Comment: Looks like that even in 2019 we have to use 3rd party app for simple text files. Wake up Google!

Comment: now it is 24, but this is still not a common feature !?

Answer (score 1):

From [Support (Drive Notepad)](https://drivenotepad.appspot.com/) :

> If you want to open another type of file you can request it in the
>   [Google+ community for Drive Notepad Users](https://plus.google.com/b/108192375095500160194/communities/107691649945880497995).

For only viewing, you can use on Chrome the extension [CodeViewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/codeviewer/pgooagjlkbcjphgofljlfdfdekdeefie/reviews).

An alternative commercial editor, [Neutron Drive](https://www.neutrondrive.com/) is not free ($28/year), but it integrates very well with Google Drive.

Comment: I downloaded codeViewer to chrome but while i am in google drive and try to "open with" i cannot see an option to open the file with codeViewer

Comment: I have no personal knowledge of CodeViewer. You might need to google for usage information.

Comment: OK so codeViewer openes only certain file (not the ones i have)

Comment: I checked the Google+ community fore Drive notepad users. and a few have asked for the ability to open any file. i dont understand why this is not the default

Comment: Me neither. To use notepad for the moment, all you can do is add your voice to the ones demanding this option, or suggest that notepad become open-source.

Comment: In Firefox I found the [Google Docs Viewer add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/google-docs-viewer-pdf-doc-doc/) that says "The add-on works with all URLs returned by Google search results. We also accept URLs that don't appear to be among the supported file types (ex., `http://example.com/?getpdf=12345`). What you need to do is to simply confirm an additional dialog indicating that you want to view it intentionally".

Comment: Link to neutron drive is dead. Here: https://super.neutrondrive.com/ The hosted version of this seems to be no more...

Answer (score 1):

You can use anyfile notepad drive app.
[Link to the app](https://anyfile-notepad.semaan.ca/app)
You can also install it directly from google drive (connect apps to drive).

After installation, right click on the file and from `open with` menu, select anyfile notepad.
Then you need to authorize.
That's it!